# tslearn neighbors no attribute "VALID_METRICS"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I tried to import tslearn.neighors classifier with the following codes:

```
import tslearn
from tslearn.neighbors import KNeighborsTimeSeriesClassifier
```

But the error message was given as:
"AttributeError: module 'sklearn.neighbors' has no attribute 'VALID_METRICS'
"
How could I resolve this problem?
Thanks!